# discord js how to delete previous message after another one command was executed

Tags: discord, discord.js

Well, i want to make a "command" or something like that which deletes the previous message from the bot after anyone has written something like (heres an example)

bot:
(message1)

user:
(anything here)

and now the bot deletes message1. is that possible? if yes howwwwww

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ClientUser.lastMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=lastMessage).

```js
// const client = new Discord.Client()

const lastMessage = client.user.lastMessage
```

From there you can do anything with it, including calling [`Message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete).

Please remember that asking on Stack Overflow should be your last resort in terms of fixing issues. Both of these could've been found in the [`Documentation`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/) easily.